# Symfony 2.8 route annotation failing

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

Have looked through SO at various Symfony routing issues but no-one seems to have the same issue as this.

Yesterday, routing worked without issue.

Today I am getting errors regarding values being required for arguments with defaults set

This is an example route that is causing me a problem

```
@Route("/summary/{staffId}", name="task_instance_summary", requirements={"staffId":"\d+"},defaults={"staffId":"0"})
```

The method definition:

```
public function summaryAction(Request $request, $staffId)
```

and of course the error:

> "Controller "PlanXL\TaskBundle\Controller\InstanceController::summaryAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$staffId" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).")

Debug output:

> [router] Route "task_instance_summary"
>
> Name         task_instance_summary
>
> Path         /task/instance/summary/{staffId}
>
> Path Regex   #^/task/instance/summary(?:/(?P\d+))?$#s
>
> Host         ANY
>
> Host Regex
>
> Scheme       ANY
>
> Method       ANY
>
> Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
>
> Defaults     _controller: PlanXLTaskBundle:Instance:summary
>
> > staffId: 0
>
> Requirements staffId: \d+
>
> Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler

I have already cleared the cache (even though I am working on dev) but I can't see why I am getting an error. The router can obviously see the default value when I run the debug so why not when called through my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it;

`public function summaryAction(Request $request, $staffId = 0)`

Comment: I know this will get rid of the error above but I really don't feel like going through my whole application and updating all my routes and method definitions to set default values when previously the annotations were working.

Comment: Ok, after messing about with converting my routing to yml instead of annotations, and getting the same errors, I gave up and have gone thjrough my application adding default values to my method declarations whenever a route throws the error.
Bizarre that only some routes are affected.